# POO JAVA - Duvida Exercicio

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Bom primeiramente segue abaixo o exercício:

> Crie uma classe chamada `Date` que inclua três partes de informações como variáveis de instância:
>   um `mês (tipo int)`, um `dia (tipo int)` e um `ano (tipo int)`.
>
> Forneça um método `set` e um `get` para cada variável de instância. Forneça um
>   método `displayDate` que exibe o mês, o dia e o ano separados por
>   barras normais ( / ).
>
> Escreva um aplicativo chamado `DateTest` que
>   demonstra as capacidades da classe Date.

Eu estou fazendo algo errado mas como estou aprendendo não consigo saber o que é.Podem me ajudar por favor

```
public class Date {

    private int dia;  

    private int mes;  

    private int ano;  

    public Date(int d, int m, int a)  
    {  
        int dia=d;
        int mes=m;
        int ano=a;
    }  
    public void setDia(int d)  
    {  
        dia = d;  
    }  
    public int getDia()  
    {  
        return dia;  
    }  
    public void setMes(int m)  
    {  
        mes = m;  
    }  
    public int getMes()  
    {  
        return mes;  
    }  
    public void setAno(int a)  
    {  
        ano = a;  
    }  
    public int getAno()  
    {  
        return ano;  
    }  
    public void displayDate()  
    {  
        System.out.printf("%d/%d/%d", getDia(), getMes(), getAno());  
    }  


    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int dia = 0;
        int mes = 0;
        int ano = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Digite o dia: " );        
        dia = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Digite o mês: " );
        mes = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Digite o ano: " );
        ano = s.nextInt();

        Date d = new date(dia,mes,ano);
        System.out.println( "A data é: " + d.displayDate() );
    }

}
```

Comment: No construtor não utilize `int dia = d` apenas `dia = d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já esta criando os parâmetros da classe nas primeiras linhas, dentro do construtor, referencie-as usando o identificador `this`. Já que está aprendendo OO, procure manter as coisas separadas. Cada classe em seu arquivo, para evitar confusão.

```
public class Date {

    private int dia;  

    private int mes;  

    private int ano;  

    public Date(int d, int m, int a)  
    {  
        this.dia=d;
        this.mes=m;
        this.ano=a;
    }  
    public void setDia(int d)  
    {  
        this.dia = d;  
    }  
    public int getDia()  
    {  
        return this.dia;  
    }  
    public void setMes(int m)  
    {  
        this.mes = m;  
    }  
    public int getMes()  
    {  
        return this.mes;  
    }  
    public void setAno(int a)  
    {  
        this.ano = a;  
    }  
    public int getAno()  
    {  
        return this.ano;  
    }  
    public String displayDate()  
    {  
       // Alterado para retornar uma String formatada em vez de printar.
       return String.format("%d/%d/%d", this.dia, this.mes, this.ano);  
    }  
}
```

```
public class DateTest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int dia = 0;
        int mes = 0;
        int ano = 0;
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Digite o dia: " );        
        dia = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Digite o mês: " );
        mes = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Digite o ano: " );
        ano = s.nextInt();

        Date d = new Date(dia,mes,ano);
        System.out.println( "A data é: " + d.displayDate() );
    }

}
```

Comment: Fiz os ajustes , mas esta dando erro na ultima linha "System.out.println( "A data é: " + d.displayDate() );"

Comment: Provavelmente porque o método displayDate tem um retorno do tipo void. Para utilizar esse método da forma que você usa no main, ele deve retornar um valor (uma string nesse caso de preferencia). Então, em vez de você dar um print no método. vc retorna a string concatenada.

Comment: @CaioSousa dá uma olhada agora.. creio que esteja corrigido.

Comment: Deu certo sim , muito Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Date(int d, int m, int a)  
{  
    this.dia=d;
    this.mes=m;
    this.ano=a;
}
```

Operador this é usado quando queremos referenciar membros da própria classe.

Depois conforme o Exercício você deve criar uma classe DateTest  e colocar o método main que hoje esta na Date.